# Redirect apache icons folder

Tags: mod-rewrite, pci-compliance

A client of mine is running an ecommerce store on godaddy shared hosting. 
They are trying to pass pci compliance and the only issue is the default apache icons folder by allowing it to be indexed. 
This folder is NOT in my web root. So I don't have access to it. 
I've tried htaccess rewrites, but it's not working. 
Anyone know of any other solutions?

Comment: What htaccess rewrites have you tried? What is the folder called (usually something like `/icons`)?

Comment: Redirecting /icons works, but redirecting /icons/ does not redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the scan is not required at level 4 with the amount of annual sales this client processes.  So, we opted to leave it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but Go Daddy shared hosting is not PCI Complaint.  You can review the last part of this page to verify that: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4265/quick-shopping-cart-pci-compliance-faq?locale=en

Comment: It's a level 4 scan and it passed with all other items with the exception of this one directory.  The scan is not required at Level 4, but the client wanted it to be able to put up a seal from her validation partner.  She's since opted out of the scan since it's not a requirement.  However, at this point, it's more about control over the content presented to visitors.  Knowing Godaddy's M.O., they have a tendency to try to force you to buy additional things (e.g. email plans), so I wouldn't be surprised if this is another tactic to buy their shopping cart.

Comment: In addition, the Link you posted says NONE of Godaddy's services are PCI compliant, with the exception of their own shopping cart.  So, the message must be: Don't use Godaddy for Ecommerce unless you plan to use their shopping cart.  Not very good for a hosting company.